# display only center (horizontally & vertically) part from img without knowing img size

Tags: html, css

I've tried many things such as table-cell but none of them worked.

All i want is an `<img src="" />` in a `<a>` tag.

The A has a given width, height and overflow:hidden;

Now how can I show only center part of img without knowing the image size?

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfLes/) and this is the code I've got:

```
<a href="">
    <img class="center" src="http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/7000000/Nature-Around-the-World-national-geographic-7018209-1440-900.jpg" />
</a>
<a href="">
    <img class="center" src="http://naturalgeographic.net/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/rock-climbing.jpg" />
</a>


<style type="text/css">
    a {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        overflow:hidden;
        border:solid 5px orange;
    }
    img.center {
        position:absolute;
        display:inline-block;
        top:-50%;
        left:-50%;
    }
</style>
```

If not possible with only those elements I can add whatever needed. BUT would like a only html/css solution no javascript.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use a background image instead of an img tag. This way you can display just the center part of an image by:

```
background:url('http://naturalgeographic.net/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/rock-climbing.jpg') no-repeat center center;
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/r4NYG/2/) is the dirty updated JSFiddle.

Comment: you might got the wrong fiddle link? there is no background-image ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to manipulate `img` width and height, without it you will not be able to put the picture relative to it's parent container. Something like this:

```
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
top: -50%; left: -50%;  
width: 200%; height: 200%;
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9JmQe/

Comment: not what I want cause image size can be verry different. but thank you for pointing to a direction